# How do I change the default value and do not allow NULL at once for a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I try to set both a default and a `NOT NULL` constraint at the same time.

I came up with

```
ALTER TABLE signedcodeofconduct ALTER COLUMN affirmed SET DEFAULT false NOT NULL;
```

which results in

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: ...eofconduct ALTER COLUMN affirmed SET DEFAULT false NOT NULL;
```

I came up with the example as I saw similar statements working, ie

```
ALTER TABLE Snap ADD COLUMN private boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL;
```

After a closer look I noticed the working example uses `ADD COLUMN` instead of `ALTER COLUMN` - and that is probably the difference.

So, is it possible to alter two things at once for a column?

At another place I was suggested to use

```
ALTER TABLE signedcodeofconduct ALTER COLUMN affirmed SET DEFAULT false IS NOT NULL;
```

which would work, but is not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a single ALTER statement, but you need to repeat the ALTER COLUMN part:

```
ALTER TABLE signedcodeofconduct 
   ALTER COLUMN affirmed SET NOT NULL,
   ALTER COLUMN affirmed SET DEFAULT false;
```